# jquery apply style when not on on a specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm trying to apply a style to my nav bar specifically when I'm on any page other than the index page however I cant seem to get it to work and I'm not sure what the issue is.

Here is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (window.location.pathname != "") {
    $('#main-nav').css('background-color', 'black');
  }
});
```

I'm using Angular 10 if that matters.

Comment: did you check what consoling  window.location.pathname in each page

Comment: $(document).ready may have been called even before your page has loaded. Since you are using angularjs. Can you try the same script on view load? For example  $viewContentLoaded event.

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov I tried it and its returning the correct pathname, however I noticed that the index page was "/" not just "". Fixing this solved the problem. I also tried using .load but it did not work so I went back to using .ready.

Comment: OR use AfterViewInit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what is the path of your index. I guess it could be "/" or "index". Check your index path, then compare the path in your code

```
if (window.location.pathname != "" 
    || window.location.pathname != "/"
        || window.location.pathname != "index") {
            $('#main-nav').css('background-color', 'black');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Angular 10 you make use of Router and add style it is very easy.
[Angular Router](https://angular.io/api/router)
Inject Angular router in you component.ts file

```
Constructur(public router: Router){
  //After Logging check the url string and add it to the ngClass condition
  console.log(router.url);
}
```

Then in your html file in your case navbar html file to the navbar tag add ngClass. [NgClass Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
[ngClass]="{'customStyle': router.url=== '/'}"
```

In your navbar component css file.

```
.customStyle{
background-color: "black"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (window.location.pathname != "" || window.location.pathname.indexOf("index")>0) {
    $('#main-nav').css('background-color', 'black');
  }
});
```